# Resize font in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-size

i have a liitle question. I would like resize all html elements in jquery. I have code but i can increase and decrease to infinity.

```
    var originalSize = $('html').css('font-size');
  // reset
   $(".resetMe").click(function(){
  $('html').css('font-size', originalSize); 

   });

   // Increase Font Size
   $(".increase").click(function(){
  var currentSize = $('html').css('font-size');
  var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*1.05;
  $('html').css('font-size', currentSize);

  return false;
   });

   // Decrease Font Size
   $(".decrease").click(function(){
  var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
  var currentSize = $('html').css('font-size');
  var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*0.8;
  $('html').css('font-size', currentSize);

  return false;
   });
```

I would like limit count of increase and decrease font size ?

How edit this code ?

Comment: Please be more specific about limits and your expectations

Comment: This is unlikely to work well. No matter what you set on the HTML element, any element with a specific font size, such as `12px`, will retain it. What is your goal?

Comment: my goal is, if i  max 3 click increasing font size and more than 3 click do not increasing more

Comment: If all you want is just to let user click no more than 3 times, I would set a counter variable, which track clicks and after third one I would prevent default action with `preventDefault`

Comment: The code should work in such a way that:
I click on the link, button or other element and the font increases by a percentage on the whole page. This is included in the above code. I would like to limit the number of clicks to increase and reduce the font size to eg 3

Comment: Yeah, and that's what counter is for.

Comment: ok, so i set var resizeCount = 0 and next condition ?

Comment: And then inside your click event handlers you increase counter's value and check if it already equals 3. If so, set event.preventDefault() in order to stop increasing or decreasing the font size.

Comment: something like this ? var originalSize = $('html').css('font-size');
var resizeCount = 0;
// reset
$(".resetMe").click(function(){
    $('html').css('font-size', originalSize);

});

// Increase Font Size
$(".increase").click(function(){
    var currentSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*1.05;
    $('html').css('font-size', currentSize);
if (resizeCount = 3) {
    event.preventDefault()
}
    return false;
});

Comment: @kwiat1990 could you help me more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes in your code, e.g. you override resizeCounter value inside your click event, because you used var in front of it or you have wrong if statement. `=` assign a new value to a variable and is not an equality operator like `==` and `===`. And yeah, you must remember that changing font size on root element will only work on child elements if you use rem or em as your font size units.

Notice that if you increase font size and then make it smaller, by next increase the counter would have its previous value (it won't be automatically resetted).

```js
var originalSize = $('html').css('font-size');
var increaseCounter = 0;
var decreaseCounter = 0;

// reset
$(".resetMe").click(function() {
  $('html').css('font-size', originalSize);
  increaseCounter = 0;
  decreaseCounter = 0;
});

// Increase Font Size
$(".increase").click(function() {
  increaseCounter += 1;

  if (increaseCounter <= 3) {
    var currentSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var biggerSize = parseFloat(currentSize) * 1.05;
    $('html').css('font-size', biggerSize);
  }
});

// Decrease Font Size
$(".decrease").click(function() {
  decreaseCounter += 1;

  if (decreaseCounter <= 3) {
    var currentSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var decreasedSize = parseFloat(currentSize) * 0.95;
    $('html').css('font-size', decreasedSize);
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button class="resetMe">reset</button>
  <button class="increase">make bigger</button>
  <button class="decrease">make smaller</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i do it like you but stil dont working well. Need I something loop ?

Comment: if i click more than 3 times still increase and decrease font size. I have in eeach html elemetnt font size in em

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's no link or form submit button, so preventDefault make here absolutely no sense.

Comment: oh thans very much :D you are the best

Comment: It's better to write code on laptop than on mobile ;) I have updated my code and added a short notice. The code could be definietely better and more elegant after some refactoring but it's totally up to you. You could add a bit more functionality, which would bring better ux to the table but as it is, it works

Comment: ;) for sure. Now its working fine. But i would like little improve. I would like use cookies or sesion to save settings on the each page on of the website. Could you help me one more time ?

Comment: and now i discovered i things. if i click 3 times to increase and 1 decrease i cant again increase

Comment: I talked about it previously, see the very last sentence of my answer. There is now no binding between this two buttons, so only click on reset button set counter again to 0.

Comment: yeah i see, i'm tryind binding this two buttons. I add `if (decreaseCounter >=0 && increaseCounter <= 3) {
  increaseCounter = increaseCounter - 1;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I do something like that and stil dont working

```
var originalSize = $('html').css('font-size');
var resizeCount = 0;
// reset
$(".resetMe").click(function(){
    $('html').css('font-size', originalSize);

});

// Increase Font Size
$(".increase").click(function(){
    var currentSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*1.05;
    $('html').css('font-size', currentSize);
    return false;
    var resizeCount =+1;
    if (resizeCount = 3) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

// Decrease Font Size
$(".decrease").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*0.95;
    $('html').css('font-size', currentSize);

    return false;
});
```